# mouseleave works but not focusout

Tags: jquery, focus, mouseevent

I'm using Jquery autocomplete, and I've created a custom focus method. The goal is to present additional information while the element is focused, then return the element to its default state on blur. Because autocomplete doesn't have a baked in blur method, I've hacked together my own using mouseleave:

```
focus: function( event, ui ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var menu = $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.element;
  var focused = menu.find("li:has(a.ui-state-focus)");
  var child = $(focused).children().first();
  var item = ui.item.value;
  var text = "<div>" + item.name + "</div>";
  if (item.publications.length > 0) text += "<div>" + item.publications + "</div>";
  $(child).html(text).attr("name", item.name);
  $(focused).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(child).html($(child).attr("name"))
  });
},
```

Although this works with a mouse rollover, it doesn't work when the user navigates up and down the list using the keyboard. For that to happen, I'd need to use something like focusout:

```
$(focused).on("focusout", function() {
  $(child).html($(child).attr("name"))
});
```

Unfortunately, focusout has no apparent effect, one way or the other. No error messages, and no altered text--not even on mouseover. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: have you tried `blur` instead of `focusout`? If the element you try to trigger focusout on is not a form element then give him `tabindex="1"` attribute.

Comment: I've given `blur` a shot, but it has the same effect as `focusout`. This is the first time I've heard about `tabindex`, but `attr('tabindex', 1)` doesn't seem to be doing the trick, either. A brief Google search suggests that `tabindex` is meant to keep track of tabbing, which in this case doesn't really affect things, as tabbing exits the autocomplete field. Thanks for the tips, though. Any others?

Answer (score 0):

Give to `li` (that `:has(a.ui-state-focus)`) the attribute `tabindex` with some value. E.g. `<li tabindex="0"><a[...]</li>`.

L.E.: `tabindex` makes possible to `focus` html elements. So they can trigger `focusout` on blur.

Comment: I give the `li` a `tabindex` of 0 like so: `child.attr('tabindex', 0)`. Using Firebug, I can see that the `li` is in fact recieving the `tabindex` attribute. Unfortunately, `focusout` still doesn't work.

Comment: Don't do it in javascript. The `li` element doesn't even focus. Put the `tabindex` in html.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `li` is generated by Jquery, so I don't have direct HTML access.